# extreme values when the determinant of the Hessian at a critical point is zero.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$ f(x,y)=\frac{x^{4}}{2}-4xy^{2}+8y^{2} $

I found 3 critical points: $(0,0),(2,2),(2,-2)$

The hessian at $(2,2),(2,-2) < 0$

and we get a saddle point.

but at $(0,0)$ the hessian is zero.

what can I do to characterize this critical point?

thanks :)

Comment: It could happen many things. Try aproaching the point from different curves and look at the sign

Comment: @LilMinho77 what you mean by different curves?

Comment: For example what happens When you approach the point from x=y and x=-y. The point could be a maximum and minimu at the same time

Comment: Actually, at $(0,0)$ the Hessean is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&16\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry I meant the determinante

Comment: @LilMinho77 but in this case x and y are both raised by the power of 2 (or 4), so is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$f(x,y)=\frac12x^4+4(2-x)y^2,$$which is greater than $0$ whenever $x<2$, unless $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Therefore, $f$ has a local minimum at $(0,0)$.